# Simplify API Creation for GraphQL Models using Hot Chocolate in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, graphql, hotchocolate

I'm relatively new to GraphQL. I've previously worked with tools like Hasura, Orchard Core, and Strapi, where the process of creating tables automatically generates basic APIs (such as GET, GETbyID, POST, DELETE) for CRUD operations. Now, I'm seeking guidance on how to achieve similar functionality in GraphQL using Hot Chocolate in a .NET environment.

In my current project, I'm dealing with six objects that require basic querying functionalities. However, I find the manual setup quite confusing and challenging to maintain. Below is an excerpt of my current implementation:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace BackEnd
{
    public class Query
    {
        public async Task<List<Question>> GetQuestions(AppDbContext dbContext)
        {
            return await dbContext.Questions.ToListAsync();
        }
        
        public async Task<List<Answer>> GetAnswers(AppDbContext dbContext)
        {
            return await dbContext.Answers.ToListAsync();
        }
        
        public async Task<List<User>> GetUsers(AppDbContext dbContext)
        {
            return await dbContext.Users.ToListAsync();
        }
        
        public async Task<List<House>> GetHouse(AppDbContext dbContext)
        {
            return await dbContext.House.ToListAsync();
        }
        
        public async Task<List<Cat>> GetCats(AppDbContext dbContext)
        {
            return await dbContext.Cats.ToListAsync();
        }
        
        public async Task<List<Dogs>> GetDogs(AppDbContext dbContext)
        {
            return await dbContext.Dogs.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any advice or guidance on how to streamline this process, perhaps utilizing Hot Chocolate's features or any other recommended approaches within the .NET ecosystem. Thank you!

I tried to improve the code structure and clarity for easier maintenance. I expected to provide a more organized and efficient solution for querying GraphQL models using Hot Chocolate in a .NET environment. The changes made include reformatting the code for better readability, providing a clear explanation of the issue, and seeking advice on optimizing the implementation.

Comment: HotChocolate is a library while Hasura is an entire service built with libraries like HotChocolate. Automagic APIs aren't as great as they sound either, because sooner or later you realize clients are executing unexpected expensive queries that you haven't optimized for. Eg searching using unindexed properties.

Comment: There *is* an equivalent automagic package, [Azure Data API Builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-api-builder/) which actually uses HotChocolate underneath. Despite the name, it's not restricted to Azure or Azure SQL at all.

Comment: Oh, I've reconsidered. Perhaps I should learn some architectural patterns and techniques for managing APIs. I'm thinking of creating something similar to IRepository to pass models through a generic T, with basic operations. This way, I can easily group APIs related to the same model together and develop additional APIs more efficiently.

Comment: What you describe is an ugly antipattern - putting a low-level CRUD named "IRepository<T>" over a high level Unit of Work like DbContext. ORMs like Entity Framework try to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables so they don't need CRUD classes.

Comment: Do check the Data Builder and the code it generates though, because it handles a lot of the requirements of an API, not just GraphQL

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified example to get you started...

Helper method to create an object type

```cs
public static ObjectTypeExtension CreateTypeExtensionAsync()
{
    var typeDefinition = new ObjectTypeDefinition(nameof(OperationType.Query)); // Adding these fields directly on Query

    foreach (var prop in typeof(AppDbContext).GetProperties())
    {
        typeDefinition.Fields.Add(
            new ObjectFieldDefinition(
                $"{prop.Name}", // the name of the field we're adding
                type: TypeReference.Parse("String!"), // the type we're returning.. it's likely a list of the first generic argument for the prop - make sure you add the type to the builder if you're not using it elsewhere
                pureResolver: ctx => prop.Name)); // actual resolver logic here
    }

    return ObjectTypeExtension.CreateUnsafe(typeDefinition);
}
```

Then at startup

```cs
var dynamicTypeExtension = CreateTypeExtensionAsync();
builder.AddTypeExtension(dynamicType);
```

This adds each property with a resolver that just returns the property name (as an example).

You can use the `PropertyInfo` get the reelevant `DbSet` from an `AppDb` instance to call your methods on.